# MVP Implementation at the UserControl Level

Tags: c#, user-interface, winforms, mvp, separation-of-concerns

I'm trying to figure out how MVP should be implemented at the `UserControl` level. I thought I had it, but I ended up reading a blog post that pretty much shut me down. Now I'm back at the start and with no idea how to proceed.

Let's say my `UserControl` is something simple like two `TextBox`es and a `ComboBox`. This gets invoked from a main form (which has its own View and Presenter). Now, the way I understand MVP is that the Main Form Presenter is supposed to invoke a second presenter to handle all communication with the UserControl that gets dropped there.

And this is where I get completely lost. My past implementations of `UserControl`s (before I learned MVP) always incorporated the logic behind the control (e.g. `ComboBox` selection will change text label related to `TextBox1`). As such, implementation of the `UserControl` is done by dragging it onto the designer, and then calling commands like `UserControl1.Update()` or `UserControl1.DisplayData(data)`.

In any third-party `UserControl`, all commands to the `UserControl` are performed by commands to the control. There is no "presenter" that needs to be invoked, for instance, when I drop a `ComboBox`, or a `ListView`, or any other WinForms control onto my form. Yet they have internal logic that dictates how they display, and in the essence of testing, it should have a "presenter" separation to it **somewhere**.

I *thought* that a good solution would be that the **constructor** of my `UserControl` would create a Presenter. Any commands to the `UserControl` would delegate straight to the Presenter. This would allow my `UserControl` to have its own presentation logic separated from its "view", such that I can test it, and such that the implementer (the Main Form) need only drop in the `UserControl` and perform data sends and receives as part of its local presentation logic. The `UserControl` has its own presentation logic left invisible to the implementer.

And just when I thought I understood it all, [I find out that it's bad practice (The Self-Aware View)](http://blog.mattwynne.net/2007/06/13/mvp-smells/). So I plead with people who understand this better than I: How do I construct a `UserControl` that keeps its presentation logic invisible to the end-user, such that I don't have to construct the wrapping presenter in my Main Form, **without** violating the principles that Matt Wynne discusses in the linked post above?

Or am I completely misunderstanding the concept of MVP here?

Answer (score 3):

I read through Matt Wynne's blog entry that you linked, and I can see where some of the confusion is coming from.  So let's point out a few differences between his article and your situation.

- Your question was asked on Aug 21st of 2013.  Matt's article was published on June 13 of **2007**.
- You tagged your question with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms), although I think you meant [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) instead of winForms. Matt states his focus and experience has been with ASP.NET.

I want to point out that we're already at a) dated advice and b) differing UI technologies.

ASP.NET and the `MV*` pattern(s) it supports have changed significantly since then.  Likewise, users of Silverlight and WPF have since generated a lot of guidance with using the `MVVM` pattern and data binding.

And as a point of reference, I would recommend reading over Martin Fowler's articles on [Passive View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html) and [Supervising Controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html) which are the patterns he broke out from his original [MVP pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/ModelViewPresenter.html).

---

I think your question is more interesting when looking at the broader point of view and asking "what does `MV*` help me with for a framework?"  And the primary driver of this family of patterns is to encapsulate the areas that are likely to change.  Related to that encapsulation is the single responsibility principle and making sure each component owns what it should.

We encapsulate all of the view logic in the `View` layer so we can more easily change out our UI technology at an appropriate point later on in time.  Likewise with the `Model` and whatever you choose to use with the middle layer.

So the answer to your question is to put the appropriate view logic within that layer to make your technology work.  If you're using winForms, you'll end up with a lot of code-behind in order to make the form work.  WPF supports data binding and significantly reduces the amount of code-behind.  The logic you put in the `View` should potentially go away when you change UI technologies.

Likewise, if you have presentation rules that are not imposed by the UI technology then you'll put those rules in your middle layer as they need to persist into your next UI.

I don't mean to diminish the fact that there are differences between the `MV*` patterns, and those differences exist for good reason.  But their development was driven by the needs of particular technologies.  You're using potentially different tech, so use the `MV*` pattern appropriate for your environment.  The frameworks are there to facilitate future change, not handcuff your current development.

Comment: A) I'm coming to realize that one should take advice with a grain of salt, though it's particularly unusual for me (my background is engineering, so things that are decades old are still relevant) where in software, something a few years old may no longer be relevant. The world changes fast here.


B) I did not mean WPF. I have little experience with WPF, though I am familiar with the mechanic of MVVM due to the background reading I've done on MV*. I do enjoy the differences between WinForms and WPF, but I have not yet decided when I'll start migrating to WPF with new development projects.

Comment: You also mention that we break out our UI into an MV* pattern so we can change the UI in the future. I think the disconnect I've been having is that I don't see WinForms changing often, where on the contrary I can see webpages through ASP.NET changing fairly frequently. At the same time, I can understand the **need** to separate the layers for any potential changes in the future, but I felt that the focus of my usage of these patterns was such that I could unit test my code. (My thought process getting to this point was: "You can unit test code" -> "How do I unit test a UI?" -> "MV*")

Comment: @Arclight - speaking as a fellow engineer, I fully agree that software is a different beast than the other fields of engineering.   You should be comfortable with applying a healthy dose of skepticism to any advice that's given until you understand the principles it is trying to advocate.  One major difference with WPF and the MV* patterns is the ability to bind elements within the view to the elements in the view model layer.  Binding gets rid of so much overhead code that you have to experience it to believe it ...

Comment: @Arclight ... And there's a nuance with the encapsulation that I don't think you quite caught.  The UI technology itself won't change - ie. winForms is "dead" and won't see anything new.  What changes is what technology you're going to use next in that application.  By having all of the UI technology specific dependencies within the View layer, it becomes that much easier to A) switch to a new technology (like WPF) and B) not re-write business logic that will persist well beyond a particular UI technology.